# Settling values on an undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a graph that has values on nodes

> value = A/B/C
>
> values = { A , B , C }

Aim: Connected nodes must have same values post settling :

Example :

> Pre settling :
>
> node1 = { A, B }
>
> node2 = { A, B, C }
>
> node3 = { D }
>
> Post  settling :
>
> node1 = { A, B ,C, D }
>
> node2 = { A, B ,C, D }
>
> node3 = { A, B ,C, D }

Settling algorithm:

Make pairs of nodes ( node1, node2 ) , ( node2, node3 ) etc.

```
didSomething = false
doWhile ( didSomething ) 
  for ( iterate all pairs ) 
   didSomething |= settle ( a-pair )
```

didSomething is true if ( node1.values != node2.values )

Problem: Some graph sets take TOO long to settle on.

**prefferably not use idea of connected components , some nodes aquire values differently from others**

> ```
> > **gprof**
> >
> >   SkipAcrossBlocks::PortSpreader::settle() [12] [13]    56.1    0.09  
> > 48.77 7367012         SkipAcrossBlocks::EdgePair::settle() [13]
> >                 0.03   45.78 7367012/7367012     bool std::operator=  
> > <SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord,
> > std::less<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord>,
> > std::allocator<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord>
> > >(std::set<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord, 
> > std::less<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord>,
> > std::allocator<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord> > const&,
> > std::set<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord,
> > std::less<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord>,
> > std::allocator<SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord> > const&) [14]
> ```
>
> SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord = "value"
>
> std::set < SkipAcrossBlocks::OneJumpRecord > " values "

gprof says
7*10^6 calls to compare equality on  "values"
takes up most time.

settling on a pair of nodes for completeness:

```
bool EdgePair::settle() {

       // if edge is internalRailORglobal should not aquire other rails

       if ( edge1->cannotAquire() && edge2->cannotAquire() ) {
          return false;
       }
       else if ( !edge1->cannotAquire() && edge2->cannotAquire() ) {
          if ( edge1->superSetOf( edge2 )) {
             return false;
          }
          edge1->spreadValues.insert( edge2->spreadValues.begin(), edge2->spreadValues.end());
          return true;
       }
       else if ( edge1->cannotAquire() && !edge2->cannotAquire() ) {
          if ( edge2->superSetOf( edge1 )) {
             return false;
          }
          edge2->spreadValues.insert( edge1->spreadValues.begin(), edge1->spreadValues.end());
          return true;
       }
       else {
          // neither are internalORglobal

          if ( edge1->spreadValues == edge2->spreadValues ) {
             return false;
          }
          edge1->spreadValues.insert( edge2->spreadValues.begin(), edge2->spreadValues.end());
          edge2->spreadValues = edge1->spreadValues;
          return true;
       }
    }
```

Following equality comparison seems to be the one taking time :

```
          if ( edge1->spreadValues == edge2->spreadValues ) {
             return false;
          }
```

I would be intersted in :

- Can set comparison be made more effective
- Other algorithms / ideas
- **prefferably not use idea of connected components , some nodes aquire values differently from others**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially compute connected components but in a very inefficient way. Since your answer does depend on connected components it is unlikely you can find some algorithm not using them.

Good news is that connected components can be computed in very fast and efficient way, see example in Boost.Graph library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/example/connected_components.cpp

Your whole flow could be:

1. numComponents = boost::connected_components(G, componentsMap);
2. vector allValues(numComponents);
3. one pass over componentsMap to populate allValues
4. one pass over allValues to associate them with vertices

Complexity will be almost linear w.r.t. to graph size.

Comment: This is ultimately what I had to do ! Thanks .